# Can Magento be configured to use discounted Fedex rates without code-level changes

Tags: fedex

Trying to figure out why, by default, the Fedex rates that are returned are not the discounted rates that we're expecting.  Found a good post on the Magento forums relevant to this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/forum/viewthread/303546/#t473550

They referenced a Magento bug report that I couldn't find:
Issue #14644

I'm currently on Enterprise 1.12.0.2 (I know I know, behind 2 major point versions.  If it turns out this issue is due to be being behind, that will be a first).

Perhaps it's just that by default they expect merchants to charge their customers list price and keep the savings for themselves.  That wouldn't be completely unreasonable.  But it's surprising that there isn't at least a configuration option for this.

UPDATE: I noticed that I got a downvote and close vote.  While this question may in part relate to a business decision that's outside the scope of a proper SO question, I think that this is still a useful question to have a cannonical answer.

After a decent bit of searching, I wasn't able to figure out why my rates were incorrect and Fedex developer support is, let's just say, not very helpful.

So, if for no other reason than to give other people a quick answer to why their rates are incorrect, I think this is a useful question to have around.

In order to make the question less subjective, I've changed it from "why don't..." to "Can Magento be configured to use discounted rates without code-level changes?".

Comment: Because a lot of people charge the book rate, pay the negotiated rate and use the difference to pay for the packaging materials. It's a business decision.

Comment: I edited the question give a bit more context and explain why I think it shouldn't be closed.  In case it was you @FiascoLabs who downvoted and close voted.

Comment: Wasn't me on the flag, it's a valid question, just noting why negotiated rates aren't the default. Plus most small operations find out later that they can negotiate rates.

Comment: Gotcha thanks.  I've now received 2 downvotes despite my clarifications.  It appears that my downfall is near.

Comment: Didn't FedEx update their API awhile ago?  I believe there exists a patch for older versions of Magento.  If you haven't already applied that, I would implement that and see if you get your expected rates.

Comment: Right good point @coasthird - I just had a look at that - http://www.webshopapps.com/blog/2014/03/fedex-web-service-change-impact-on-magento-free-patch/ - apparently if that were the cause, then I wouldn't be seeing rates at all.  So I don't think that's the case.

Comment: After reviewing the freight setups, I see that the modules are different, UPS has a setting for Negotiated Rates and Fedex doesn't. Ouch. From what I've read, Fedex enables negotiated rates through their web services. You sign up for the web services account on the Fedex website in their developer resource center which then provides the Account number, Authentication key number, Meter number.  A separate Production password is emailed to provide access to your rates. Sounds like you have to call Fedex and make sure the returned rates are your negotiated rates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the answer to this is no.  I had to go with code-level changes in order to get Fedex to use the ACCOUNT rates as opposed to the LIST rates.

Update: for reference here is the core code change that was needed.

[image]

Comment: Hello @kalenjordan, I am having same issue in Magento 2, Do you have solution for magento 2 ?